# How can implement a recursive lock using boost, that spans multiple methods?

Tags: c++, boost, recursive-mutex

I have a class that opens transactions, adds operations to a queue, then closes the transaction. Across the open->close lifetime I would like to employ a recursive mutex, so that only one thread can have a transaction open at any time. All other threads are blocked until the current transaction is ended.

```
class MyObject
{
  void beginTransaction()
  {
    // acquire mutex
  }

  void endTransaction()
  {
    // release mutex
  }

  boost::recursive_mutex m_mutex;
}
```

I am having difficulty determining how I can use a `recursive_mutex` in this case, as the lock would exist longer than the scope of a single method. Can anyone suggest how I might apply locking here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boost (and the standard library) provide **mutexes**, which can be locked and unlocked, and **locks**, which lock mutexes in their constructor and unlocks them in their destructor. Locks are really just lightweight wrappers that are used to ensure a lock is released when leaving scope.

In your case, you would just use the mutex directly, without wrapping it in a lock.

You can call `m_mutex.lock()` in `beginTransaction` to lock the mutex, then `m_mutex.unlock()` in `endTransaction` to unlock the mutex. If another thread attempts to call `m_mutex.lock()` between calls, it will block until the mutex is unlocked by the owning thread in `endTransaction`